# Given Gaussian "noise" matrix $G$ and matrix products $AG$, and $A^\intercal AG$, solve for $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, random-matrices, singular-values

> Given Gaussian "noise" matrix $G$ and matrix products $AG$, and $A^\intercal AG$, solve for $A$
>
> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a matrix with rank $k$. Consider the following randomized procedure:
>
> 1. Draw a matrix $G \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ with i.i.d $N(0,1)$ Gaussian entries.
> 2. Form the matrix $Y = AG \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times k}$
> 3. Form the matrix $Z = A^\intercal Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$
>
> Is it possible to reconstruct $A$ and its singular value decomposition from the information provided by the matrices $(G,Y,Z)$? If yes, then specify an algorithm. If no, then provide a counterexample.

My work:

We are trying to solve for $A$ given $G,AG,A^\intercal AG$.

For vector $\vec{v}$ in inner product space $X$, use the notation $(\vec{v})^*: X \to \mathbb{R}$, $\vec{x} \mapsto = {\langle \vec{v}, \vec{x} \rangle}$.

SVD decompositions:

\begin{gather*}
    A = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \vec{u}_{A,i} \sigma_{A,i} (\vec{v})^*_{A,i}, \quad
    A^\intercal = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \vec{v}_{A,i} \sigma_{A,i} (\vec{u})^*_{A,i}, \quad
    G = \sum\limits_{t=1}^k \vec{u}_{G,t} \sigma_{G,t} (\vec{v})^*_{G,t} \\
    \vec{u}_{A,i} \in \mathbb{R}^m, \; \vec{v}_{A,i} \in \mathbb{R}^n, \quad \vec{u}_{G,i} \in \mathbb{R}^n, \; \vec{v}_{G,i} \in \mathbb{R}^k \\
\end{gather*}

\begin{align*}
    A^\intercal A &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^k (\vec{v}_{A,i} \sigma_{A,i} (\vec{u})^*_{A,i}) \sum\limits_{j=1}^k (\vec{u}_{A,j} \sigma_{A,j} (\vec{v})^*_{A,j})
    = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \vec{v}_{A,i} \sigma_{A,i}^2 (\vec{v})^*_{A,i} \\
    AG &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^k (\vec{u}_{A,i} \sigma_{A,i} (\vec{v})^*_{A,i}) \sum\limits_{t=1}^k (\vec{u}_{G,t} \sigma_{G,t} (\vec{v})^*_{G,t})
    = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \sum\limits_{t=1}^k \vec{u}_{A,i} \sigma_{A,i} {\langle \vec{v}_{A,i}, \vec{u}_{G,t} \rangle} \sigma_{G,t} (\vec{v})^*_{G,t} \\
    A^\intercal AG &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^k (\vec{v}_{A,i} \sigma_{A,i}^2 (\vec{v})^*_{A,i}) \sum\limits_{t=1}^k (\vec{u}_{G,t} \sigma_{G,t} \vec{v}^*_{G,t})
    = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \sum\limits_{t=1}^k \vec{v}_{A,i} \sigma_{A,i}^2 {\langle \vec{v}_{A,i}, \vec{u}_{G,t} \rangle} \sigma_{G,t} (\vec{v})^*_{G,t} \\
\end{align*}

We have two systems of equations:

\begin{align*}
    \sum\limits_{r=1}^k \vec{u}_{AG,r} \sigma_{AG,r} (\vec{v})^*_{AG,r} &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \sum\limits_{t=1}^k \vec{u}_{A,i} \sigma_{A,i} {\langle \vec{v}_{A,i}, \vec{u}_{G,t} \rangle} \sigma_{G,t} (\vec{v})^*_{G,t} \\
    \sum\limits_{s=1}^k \vec{u}_{A^\intercal AG,s} \sigma_{A^\intercal AG,s} (\vec{v})^*_{A^\intercal AG,s} &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \sum\limits_{t=1}^k \vec{v}_{A,i} \sigma_{A,i}^2 {\langle \vec{v}_{A,i}, \vec{u}_{G,t} \rangle} \sigma_{G,t} (\vec{v})^*_{G,t} \\
\end{align*}

This looks like it can be solved but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.